# Independent chain cancellation in redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, react-redux, redux-observable

I'm new to RxJS. In my app I need independent cancellation of deferred action. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/gayoti/edit?js,output) a working example (the delay is 3 seconds). But when I choose to delete multiple items and cancel one of them, then canceled all at once.

Epic code:

```
const itemsEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('WILL_DELETE')
    .flatMap(action =>
      Observable.of({type: 'DELETE', id: action.id})
        .delay(3000)
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType('UNDO_DELETE'))
  )
```

I think I need to pass an `id` to `takeUntil` operator, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the `takeUntil` operator correctly, it stops emitting new items from the `Observable` it was called on, once the argument `Observable` emits it's first item. With this in mind you could do something like this:

```
const itemsEpic = action$ => action$.ofType('WILL_DELETE')
  .flatMap(action => Observable.of({ type: 'DELETE', id: action.id })
    .delay(3000)
    .takeUntil(action$.ofType('UNDO_DELETE').filter(({id}) => id === action.id))
  )
```

Comment: You seem to understand it perfectly. This is exactly what you would do.

Comment: This solution works exactly as expected.
Thank you very much.